# Google maps Geo reverse location loop & time interval

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

What im trying to do is. I read a RSS feed about police reports etc. the code would refresh the rss page every 30+ seconds and add all the data into the database with the lon & lat.

The thing is, i want to get the street address using reverse geo location. it works well but it only gives the address of the last item in the php loop. is there a way i can get all the streets using the code below?

```
    $xml=("http://feeds.livep2000.nl");

function getFeed($feed_url) {

    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
    $conn = new Connection; 
    $x->registerXPathNamespace('rdf', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#');
    $x->registerXPathNamespace('content', 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/');
    $x->registerXPathNamespace('geo', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#'); 
    $i = 0;
    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) 
    {
        $geolat = $entry->xpath('geo:lat');
        $geolon = $entry->xpath('geo:long');
        if($geolat != "" && $geolon != ""){
            $checkifexists = $conn->query("SELECT `alerts` FROM `alerts_p2000` WHERE `lat` = '".$geolat[0]."' AND `lon` = '".$geolon[0]."'");
            if($checkifexists->num_rows == '0')
            {

                $sql = "INSERT INTO `alerts_p2000` (`title`,`lat`,`lon`,`date_added`,`cat`)
                VALUES ('".$conn->real_escape_string($entry->title)."','".$geolat[0]."','".$geolon[0]."',now(),'68')";
                $conn->query($sql);
                $alert_id = $conn->inserted_id();

                $description = "<b>".$conn->real_escape_string($entry->description)."</b>";
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `alerts_content_p2000` (`description`,`alert_id`,`img`)VALUES('".$description."','".$alert_id."','68/politie')";
                $conn->query($sql);
                $alertcontent_id = $conn->inserted_id();

                $sql = "UPDATE `alerts_p2000` SET `alert_content_id` = '".$alertcontent_id."' WHERE `alerts` = '".$alert_id."'";
                $conn->query($sql);
                $i++;

                ?>
                <script>
                    console.log('test');

                    var app = angular.module('app', []);

                    app.controller('mainctrl', function($scope, $filter) 
                    {
                        ///// HIER DE CODE
                        $scope.alerts = {};
                        $scope.alerts.lat = <?php echo $geolat[0]; ?>;
                        $scope.alerts.lon = <?php echo $geolon[0]; ?>;
                        console.log($scope.alerts);
                        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                        var yourLocation = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.alerts.lat, $scope.alerts.lon);
                        console.log('first test');

                        geocoder.geocode({ "latLng": yourLocation }, function (results, status) 
                        {
                            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
                            {
                                if(results[0]) 
                                {
                                    var numberobj = $filter('filter')(results[0].address_components, {types: "street_number"})[0];
                                    $scope.alerts.number = numberobj.long_name;

                                    var streetobj = $filter('filter')(results[0].address_components, {types: "route"})[0];
                                    $scope.alerts.street = streetobj.long_name;

                                    var cityobj = $filter('filter')(results[0].address_components, {types: "locality"})[0];
                                    $scope.alerts.city = cityobj.long_name;
                                    $scope.$apply();

                                    console.log('' + $scope.alerts.street + ' ' + $scope.alerts.city);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    </script>
                <?

            }   
        }
    }
    echo $i.' nieuwe alerts';
}

echo getFeed($xml);
```

lets say i have 4 new feed items the code show 'test' 4 times but the address only once

EDIT: So with the new information i'd like to find a way to limit the request to once per second by a timerinterval, but placing a timeinterval or timeout doesnt do the trick for me

Comment: There are limits for geocoding requests. Please read: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits and https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat

Comment: The code is geolocate code js? is that always client sided? which means no limit?

Comment: What? What are you talking about? Did you read the 2 links I provided?

Comment: Yes, but it just shows the limits. im confident i work client side so there is no limit to the use of geolocation(according to the link) *Note: These limits apply to the Google Geocoding web service which is primarily intended for server-side geocoding.*

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. But the document also mentions: *This service is also available as part of the Google Maps JavaScript API* so I believe the same limitations apply for the JavaScript API.

Comment: Hmmm i see. i think *In addition, the Web Service is rate-limited, so that requests that come in too quickly result in blocking.* gives me quite a good answer as why it only gives the last address the requests all come within 1 seconds which is probably too fast

Comment: Yes. Bare in mind that the geocoder is asynchronous and that it is limited to 5 requests per second. If you watch your javascript console and if you hit the limit, you should see a warning: `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`